# bower only getting .bower.json file

Tags: bower, bower-install

so I'm having a weird issue where bower seems to only be downloading the .bower.json file for ~25% of my packages that I have installed in my projects bower.json file.

To temporarily remedy the issue, I uninstalled and reinstalled all of the broken packages, and it seemed to work last night until this morning. I haven't been able to identify any relation between the broken packages, as some of them I've been using since the beginning of this project, and others I've recently installed. I've tried reverting to older version that I know are stable, with no luck.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue and knows how to solve it? Thank you! If you need any more information, I'm happy to provide it (Not sure what else will be useful).

Comment: update 1: clearing the bower cache did not work.

Comment: update 2: the packages in question are:
eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker
node-uuid
oboe
seiyria-bootstrap-slider

Comment: update 3: it seems that when I uninstall and reinstall these packages, they get downloaded the very first time successfully, but thereafter they only download the .bower.json file.

Comment: update 4: I'm using version 1.4.1 of bower

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing the same thing with bower install requirejs